# Add a mouseListener to a JTable having mysql data

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have this class,that takes values from mysql database,i want to add a **mouselistener** that has this function:

-Select a **row** or a **cell** on jtable and **modify** the selected value or **delete** the selected row.

-the changes made on the JTable should be **visible** even in the table of the **mysql database**

it is possible to do ? thanks.

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.sql.*;
 import java.util.*;

 import javax.swing.*;

 import DataBaseConnectionSingleton.Connection;
 import DataBaseConnectionSingleton.CreationStatement;

 public class ShowEmployee extends JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ShowEmployee() {
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

    try {

        Connection.getConnectionInstance();
        Statement st = CreationStatement.getCreationStatementInstance();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from employee");
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = md.getColumnCount();

        // Get column names

        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
            columnNames.addElement(md.getColumnName(i));
        }

        // Get row data

        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
            }

            data.addElement(row);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    // Create table with database data

    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames) {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++) {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null) {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
    };

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ShowEmployee frame = new ShowEmployee();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: U-u-u-u, what about this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464638/insert-update-delete-rows-of-jtable-having-mysql-data/21464882#21464882)? Is your question if I'm not wrong.

Comment: i ' m trying very ways to implements this,i want to implements not huge code...

Comment: Well, good luck. I don't think you will find many other ways to do this but you can keep trying.

Comment: _"it is possible to do ?"_ Yes it is possible.